# How to add package nuGet to the project after it is published

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a project asp.net mvc5
Hua was heavily on the packages and after what was published on azure.com
 I didn't find the packages work at all.
I want what are the steps to implement the packages on the server.

[image]

Comment: you should use `Manage Nuget Packages` option

Comment: Packages don't do anything by themselves, you'll have to write code that uses the types from the assemblies contained within the packages.